# how to delete a single specific value within a repl database?

Tags: python, discord, replit

Im making a discord python bot using repl's database function and i cant figure out how to delete only one value from the database.

```
@client.command()
async def addvalue(ctx, arg):
 db[str(ctx.author.id)] = [arg]
 await ctx.send("value added")

@client.command()
async def removevalue(ctx, arg):
 db[str(ctx.author.id)] = db[str(ctx.author.id)] - arg #ik this is a dumb way of trying this, this is just theory obv this wouldnt work
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I had to do was find the index of the of the value that I want to be deleted:

```
async def removevalue(ctx, arg):
  c = 0
  for x in db[str(ctx.author.id)]:
    if str(arg) in db[str(ctx.author.id)][c]:
      del db[str(ctx.author.id)][c]
      await ctx.send("Value deleted")
    return
    else:
      c += 1
```

Note that I put `str()` around `arg` but I'm pretty sure that was useless. I was just trying everything to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used it before but from looking at the [example code](https://github.com/replit/replit-py/blob/master/examples/db/db_jsonkey.py#L34) it seems you can just use:

```
del db[str(ctx.author.id)][index]
```

From [the docs](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjM-5H1rY70AhU6JDQIHdYRAtkQFnoECBIQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.replit.com%2Fhosting%2Fdatabase-faq&usg=AOvVaw1vqRG0VFfv5Ew-pmKyBL8g) it's just a key/value store so it seems it acts the same as any `dict`.

Comment: This would delete all of the values of the key, i want it to only remove one.