# To remove a specific value from a databank(replit) in python

Tags: python-3.x, replit

iam trying to remove a specific value from a "Replit" databank and i cant find the correct way.
Can somebody jut shove my nose in the right direction ?

```
user_input = "a"  

def check(user_input):
  if user_input in db["passwords"]:
    db["used_password"] = user_input
    print("correct")
  else:
    print("false")
 
check(user_input)
```

Answer (score 0):

[how to delete a single specific value within a repl database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69917912/how-to-delete-a-single-specific-value-within-a-repl-database)
Does the solution that this user presented help?

Comment: hey thanks, but that's not the answer Iam searching for.
I need the command to delete a specific value from a key.
Key    = passwords
Value  = "a"